# JavaScript validation in ation page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Considering I have a form with several input fields that has an action page on submit.
Once I fill up the data on the form and submit it, the action page will take care of all the database action with php.

If I want to validate the form fields with JavaScript, what is the best way to do it? Since I can't just display alert because the action page will redirect me to the initial page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onsubmit`:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

If you return true from javascript validateForm function then action will take place and if you return false then it will not go to action page.

Comment: @AJ thanks, that worked wonders! How can I check if a field is empty in JS?

Comment: ` var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
       alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }`
myForm is form name and fname is the field name

Comment: @AJ that's what I did, but what if a user just enters a space like " ", that would not be an acceptable name. Is there a way to check if it has characters?

Comment: use trim() method. var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value.trim(); if (x == null || x == "") { alert("Name must be filled out"); return false; }

Comment: Did trim() function help? :)